# How to return data from an Activity that is called from a Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

Basically I'm creating an Activity from my Service that uses an AlertDialog to ask the user what file they want if there is a conflict during a sync to a backend server. Since the Activity is being created inside a service I cannot use startActivityForResult(...);.  I know it is frowned upon and it would be better to use a notification. I am doing it this way because the devices that will run this app are being used specifically for this software and all the apps will be using this service for syncing to a central database.

Is there any other way to send data back from the activity to the service that calls it besides startActivityForResult(...)?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do it.  One is to use AIDL to allow the service and activity to communicate via function calls (Android will turn them into RPCs as necessary).  That requires a lot of work, but its a useful technique.  Another way would be to use a custom intent, and have the service create a broadcast receiver for that intent and notify it via a message to its handler.